# hyperref in Texmaker not making clickable links in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, texmaker

I am using Texmaker 3.1 on Windows 7 (also tried Texmaker 3.3.3 with the same result) with a MikTeX 2.9 back end to compile a document where I would like the table of contents to link to the pages. For this I normally use the `hyperref` package, and this has worked before in Texmaker on other machines.

On my present machine, Texmaker compiles without complaints, but in the resulting output the table of contents entries are not clickable. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=black
}

\oddsidemargin 0.0in
\textwidth 6.5in


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{First Section}

This is the first section.

\newpage

\section{Second Section}

This is the second section.

\subsection{A Subsection}
This is a subsection.

\end{document}
```

In this example I've coloured the links blue to demonstrate that my output does colour links correctly (my table of contents has blue entries) but nothing is clickable. In addition no PDF bookmarks are available in the output when I open it in Acrobat.

Since Texmaker isn't complaining about missing packages, etc., I'm at a loss as to what's going wrong.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE: I have got the Texmaker 3.1 version producing correct, clickable output now, but I'm not convinced this issue can be considered 'answered'. To share the stop-gap solution: I changed the settings in Texmaker for QuickBuild to be "pdfLaTeX + View PDF." This still doesn't explain why the other methods available for ending up with a PDF file don't work with the clickable table of contents entries, however.

UPDATE: As no responses have come at the original Stack Overflow location for this question, I am posting it here to expose it to the expert TeXnicians on this site.

Comment: Which underlying TeX distribution do you use? I'm guessing it's either TeXLive (2011?) or MikTeX (2.9?), but it's worth being explicit about this. After all, TeXmaker is "just" a front-end to whatever TeX engine that does the actual work... For what it's worth, when I run your MWE through MikTeX2.9 on a Windows Vista (gasp) machine and open the resulting pdf file in either Acrobat or Adobe Reader, all bookmarks one would expect to see are there.

Comment: @Mico I've added the information about the distribution (MikTex 2.9, as you guessed).  I've found this trouble occurs on my MacBook Pro using (confirmatory sigh) Windows Vista whereas my successful runs on a desktop machine were under Windows XP, so it was tempting to wonder whether that had something to do with it.  The mystery is that I installed exactly the same (portable) MikTex and Texmaker files between my the XP and Vista machines, and yet I encountered this problem only in the case of Vista.

Answer (score 1):

It has obviously nothing to do with Texmaker or any other editor. I compiled your MWE first with Texworks 0.4.4 (1043) and then with Texmaker 3.3.4, both on Windozs 7 Enterprise.

In both cases the links in the table of contents was clickable and brought me to the correct section.

So it is something with your system setup. Are you sure your version of `hyperref` is not corrupt? Try:

```
\usepackage{bookmarks}
```

`bookmarks` is part of the [Oberdiek-bundle](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek). See the documentation at [CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/bookmark).

And check your `latex`-engine. You are sure are using `PDFLaTeX`-profile so you are compiling PDFs directly and not indirectly using `DVI->PDF`?

UPDATE: As you say in your UPDATE: You have used the wrong profile (or the wrong options to the package). Try compile with the old profile but set `dvips`or similar option (see page 3 in the `hyperref`'s users manual).

You also write in your updated question:

> This still doesn't explain why the other methods available for ending up with a PDF file don't work with the clickable table of contents entries, however.

Yes, this explain why. If you want clickable links using another engine than `PDFLaTEx`, you have to load `hyperref`with correct options for the engine.